# Why on earth can't Excel handle 2 files with the same name?

Tags: excel

This bothers me for my whole IT life - I worked with 7 different versions of Excel over 20 years now, with big changes in each version, forcing me to search where the old features are hidden in the new version - but one single thing stays solid as a rock: the disability to open two files with the same name.

> Sorry, Excel can't open two workbooks with the same name at the same time.

So I'm really longing for an insight here, why this is still the case in Excel 2013, which was not even necessary to implement in Excel 95? Is there any technical or design reason within the Excel data structures or internal processings that it can't handle two File objects with diffenrent paths but the same file name? I don't want no Microsoft bashing here, I just want to understand the reason behind it.

Comment: Voted to migrate to Super User. Not in any way related to programming.

Comment: @brettdj: I thought about the same myself, but since it is not an application usage question, but about the technical reason behind it, which in turn refers to the implementation, I would say it does fit in here as well.

Comment: No other software I use has this problem. "Sorry, Mozilla Firefox can't open two files named index.html at the same time."

Comment: @ColonelPanic How would you solve [the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21773920/11683) due to which Microsoft put this restriction?

Comment: @Gserg, why not replace "Book1.xlsx" with the full path? I mean, if you are still writing formulas referencing external Excel spreadsheets in 2015 (let alone 2022), the least you could do is appreciate the need for very explicit and cumbersome syntax.

Comment: @WesleyKitlasten I don't know, I can only speculate. Because it's a breaking change which is a huge deal for Excel formulas? Because then a spreadsheet created in Office on Windows won't even work in Office on Mac? Because then it will be impossible to refer to standard common files (add-ins etc) that are expected to be in each user's folder? Because then it will be impossible to deliver two related Excel files as a bundle (where one refers to another) - you'd need to place them on a fixed path on your hard drive for them to work?

Comment: @WesleyKitlasten Because then it will be impossible to refer to opened files from VBA by name only, you'd have to know the full path, and then see the previous problem? Because it will lengthen the formula greatly, and it already has a rather low character limit?

Comment: Those all seem like legitimate excuses, esp 10 years ago. Just hard to believe something as silly as opening two distinctly different files from different locations is such a huge issue for M$oft. Then again, it is hard to believe people still rely on formulas written in Excel spreadsheets. I can’t think of a single computational problem that wouldn’t be made easier by exporting to csv and opening outside of Excel. I suppose I just need to find a better GUI for quick inspection and let sleeping dinosaurs lay.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Microsoft say [here](http://blogs.office.com/2009/01/08/why-cant-i-open-two-files-with-the-same-name/) it's due to calculation ambiguity with linked cells.

> If you had a cell ='[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$G$33 and you had two books
>   named 'Book1' open, there's no way to tell which one you mean.

This way of referring to linked workbooks by name in cells persists through all versions, and I doubt very much it will change.

Comment: Let's now think. Which percent of users who encounter that frustrating restriction of opening two files with the same name, actually had that kind of link in one of the documents? My guess is 0.001%. So, because of 0.001% of users, 99.9999% should find the workaround, renaming files, etc. Isn't it stupid? Why just don't allow to open that files and give an error ONLY if the reference like that actually exist (or simple do not calculate such cells and give an error when user click on it).

Answer (score 12):

---

**YES YOU CAN!!! (But I think this is an Excel bug)**

---

Try this:

1. On your Desktop right click and choose "New" => "Microsoft Excel
   worksheet".
2. Rename the file to "Test[1].xlsx" (the name is important!)
3. Now create a now folder on the desktop and paste a copy of the file "Test[1].xlsx" into it
4. Open both "Test[1].xlsx" via double click: **Et voilà!**

Now the two (same named) workbooks are open in Excel. But if you look into there "Workbook.Name"-Properties, it gets even more strange, because internally they are both renamed to "Test(1).xlsx".

That's because Excel does need the special characters "[]" internally for its formulas.

So they are (normally) not allowed for a workbook name, but a workbook which is named "Test[1].xlsx" externally can be opened anyway, what is **a bug** for me!

Why? Because you really get into trouble as a programmer if you want to address both of this workbooks by using "Application.Workbooks[name]", which does not fail, but delivers always the first one found by this name!

Jörg

Comment: interesting answer @jreichert, can you please explain "Workbook.Name"-Properties piece? Should I run that in command prompt or something?

Comment: @Ashrith: Go to excel VBA immediate window (ALT + F11, CTRL + G). Usage: See https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/vba-immediate-window-excel/
Then type: ?Application.Workbooks(1).Name
and hit return...

Answer (score 11):

For all the people who end up here, because they would like to open two Excel files with the same name at the same time:

Even though Excel itself does not permit to do so due to (certainly questionable) circumstances stated by Baldrick in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21773920/1236781), there at least exist workarounds which allow to open multiple xls/xlsx files with the same name at the same time in separate Excel instances/processes.

The workarounds are explained in [this thread on the How-To Geek forums](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/open-spreadsheets-in-completely-separate-windows).

There is even a sort of "built-in" fix with help of the setting `Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)`, which works for me, but leads to errors when closing Excel and then trying to open a file again by double-clicking on it.

I had to to go for the registry fix, which works fine. **NOTE THOUGH** that this workaround, once applied, will prevent cross-referencing cells between ALL opened Excel tables (also those with different names), since the separate Excel instances are not aware of each other (at least according to tests I just made).

You may instead want to choose the fix which adds a new context menu item `Open Separate` to the Explorer and only use it if you in fact want to open two files with the same name at the same time.

Comment: Very good link, thanks - in fact I already tried that from some other source with principally opening in a separate instance, but retreated from it again, but I think I'd go for the context menu item to open it separately if needed.