# Excel open same names files

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a button in Excel that opens a dialog box and I select the file that I recorded on the second sheet, but I also automatically select other files with the same name differs just ending. So I need to choose one file, and always record 2-3 more with the same name and to open a new worksheet. How to do it?

What you need to select the file abc.txt and uploaded to other files abc.ydd and abc.dyk name will always be the same only the ending will be different.

Comment: If you need to "consult with" Excel, does it also answer you? LOL! Maybe it does when you press F1... ;-)  On your problem: In general it's not difficult to choose a file, extract the filename without extension and search for other files with same name and different extension. That's what you're about to do. But what have you done so far?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but I really do not know how to do it. Macros have not learned much, could you help me with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why on earth can't Excel handle 2 files with the same name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773840/why-on-earth-cant-excel-handle-2-files-with-the-same-name)

Answer (score 1):

An advice for any work you are doing: Break down your big task into small steps as often as needed until the steps are small enough so that you know how to process them.

On your specific programming task, this means, you should break it down into:

1. You need a button on one of the excel sheets.
2. That button has to open a dialog box for selecting a file

I don't know whether it can be any arbitrary file or a specific one, as you wrote that the file was recorded on another sheet. I think that makes no difference at all.

3. After finishing the file selection, you have to evaluate the result of the dialog box (OK -> which file, ABORT -> do nothing).
4. Take the file name, remove the extension and search for other files (in the same directory or elsewhere) with that name.
5. I don't know why you want to open another worksheet. Of course you can do that, but if you want to show the content of that files in the worksheet, they better be excel files.

How you do these suggested steps is something you need to find out by yourself. Or you are lucky and find someone else who has plenty of free time to do that for you, but I don't think you will be that lucky, especially after providing a quite vague description of your problem.
In general, stackoverflow is for asking for solutions to specific programming problems, not for providing ready-to-use solutions for beginners. Take a look at VBA manuals and tutorials. They can be found widely across the internet and in book stores.