# VBA open worksheet fail

Tags: vba

```
Sub TEST()

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Desktop\TEST\TEST\TEST2.xlsx")

Workbooks("C:\Desktop\TEST\TEST\TEST2.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 1
End Sub
```

it gives me subscript out of range in the 3rd line

However, if I try

```
Workbooks("TEST2.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 1
```

This works, I am sure the path is correct, the file can be opened in the second line. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use variables to scope your objects, see if this helps:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\TEST\TEST\TEST2.xlsx")
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 1
```

The problem in your original code:

```
Workbooks("C:\Desktop\TEST\TEST\TEST2.xlsx")
```

That is *not* the name of the Workbook. The `Name` of the workbook is simply `"TEST2.xlsx"`, so as you observed, this would work (but the above method would be preferable):

```
Sub TEST()

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Desktop\TEST\TEST\TEST2.xlsx")

Workbooks("TEST2.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: @JiaoyanHuang OK cheers. so the way we thank people here is by marking answers as "Accepted". If this has solved your problem, do consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Excel refers to workbooks by the filename, not including the path. You demonstrated that with the fact that your second method works.

A consequence of that is questions like [Why on earth can't Excel handle 2 files with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21773840/1115360)